# Wordpress Dashboard Menu gives 404 error when i click any menu

Tags: php, wordpress

When i click on any menu for example:
Appearance it give 404 error or when i click on plugin it gives same error.

I tried deactivating all the plugins and deactivating all the themes but it didn't fixed the issue.
I am using latest version on wordpress.
Video Link for error.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4103600?key=b2d1b3ee88c2b8bf570e1fe298c14eb1

While installing new wordpress it gives following error:

! A test of the selected domain has failed (HTTP error: 404).

Installatron is unable to install on a domain that is not resolving/loading to this web account.

If this is a new web hosting account, or if this is a newly registered domain, please allow up to 24 hours for the domain to begin working (though usually within a few hours).

If you're sure that the domain is correctly loading to your web account, contact your web hosting administrator.

```
Technical Error: [1] Written file `/home/dgne6u5hdy4k/public_html/wp/deleteme.chabrxa4.php' not accessible at `https://anvarluxury.com/wp/deleteme.chabrxa4.php'.
2021-06-12 01:53:17.12535200 FAILURE [3; /usr/bin/curl] https://anvarluxury.com/wp/deleteme.chabrxa4.php?n=6&m=7 [http code=404] @92.205.4.113(92.205.4.113)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be with .htaccess file !
Try deleting the .htaccess file and then create a fresh .htaccess file and enter the code below as it is

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

If problem exists then try search it in WordPress documentation and guide

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4103600?key=b2d1b3ee88c2b8bf570e1fe298c14eb1

Comment: Check this video 
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4103600?key=b2d1b3ee88c2b8bf570e1fe298c14eb1

Comment: There's some kind of server error try contacting your server provider....  Hey man ! Was it working before and now acting strange ? If it was working correctly before then try reinstalling wordpress ( create a backup first ) .

Comment: Check this url from wordpress docs. https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Comment: I did everything. but nothing worked at all.

Comment: Can u tell me which server are you running on your website ?  Is it Apache or Nginx or any other

Comment: Try contacting your web hosting administrator to solve this ...  What I think is there is no problem with WordPress (but server )

Comment: This is the DNS issue. I need to point A record to hosting IP. It solved the problem.